# Sessions + redirection don't seem to be working

Tags: php, forms, session, redirect, post

So I'm working on a simple PHP log in form. My first page is index.php with a form that posts to process.php

```
    <form action="process.php" method="POST">

<li><label>Username: </label><input type="text" name="user"> </input></li>

<li><label>Password: </label><input type="password" name="pass"></input></li>

<li><label> </label><input type="submit" name="loginbutton" value="Log In" id="button"></li>
</form>
```

Simple HTML, nothing complicated. On the next page I have something in the beginning that looks like this:

```
   

    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pass'];

    header('Location: thirdpage.php');
```

On the thirdpage.php I would like to `echo $_SESSION['name'];`, but it simply doesn't work; nothing appears on the page. I feel that I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: Are you using [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) on every page that uses the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process.php:

```
start_session();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pass'];

header('Location: thirdpage.php');
```

thirdpage:

```
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

This should work, you must always perform a `session_start();` when you wish to work with a session variable.

This is an example, you should perform validations on your POST array, if you are going to be using this in full prduction